# Can you create an in-cell formula based on difference cell values?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a workbook with over 50 sheets, each one with the exact same structure. I want to make a sheet ("MAIN") that pulls the same data from each of the worksheets. For example: three sheets are named "2015_01", "2016_01", and "2017_01" and MAIN has columns "2015", "2016", and "2017" with a row directly beneath each "01", "01", "01".

I want to pull cell A9 from each of those sheets and put it into a the corresponding column, but also change the sheet it pulls from depending on the sheet title. Would it be better to do this as VBA or some sort of function?

Comment: With 50 sheets VBA seems natural, though `INDIRECT()`, with concatenation (`&`) being used to assemble the references, can probably be used for a spreadsheet formula only approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example in your OP, using the approach in the first comment:

If

```
Sheet1!A1 is "2015" and Sheet1!A2 is "01"
Sheet1!B1 is "2016" and Sheet1!B2 is "01"
Sheet1!C1 is "2017" and Sheet1!C2 is "01"
```

Then use these formulas in row 3.

```
Sheet1!A3 = '=INDIRECT(A1&"_"&A2&"!C9";TRUE)'
Sheet1!B3 = '=INDIRECT(B1&"_"&B2&"!C9";TRUE)'
Sheet1!C3 = '=INDIRECT(C1&"_"&C2&"!C9";TRUE)'
```